# A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask$TaskAction. Cannot find built manifest

Tags: flutter, gradle

I tried updating version of *targetSdkVersion* and *compileSdkVersion* it didn't work.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask$TaskAction
> Cannot find built manifest for SerializedForm(versionCode=1, versionName=1.0.0, variantOutputConfiguration=VariantOutputConfigurationImpl(isUniversal=false, filters=[]), baseName=debug, fullName=debug, outputFileName=app-debug.apk)

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
  BUILD FAILED in 4m 37s
  Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Answer (score 0):

"Sir, I encountered a problem similar to yours, and I managed to solve it.

I tried the following approach:

Copy all the code to a new file.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).